# Socket error while running wakaama DM server on raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

While running a device management server on raspberry pi, I encountered an error saying "error opening socket".

Can anybody help ?

Thanks in advance
Praveen

Comment: Can you please post some example code or output?

Comment: Thanks for reply , pi@iottue /home/praveen/wakaama/tests/server $ ./lwm2mserver
Error opening socket: 97 - this is the out put.

Comment: The source code of the test server is on github
https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama.git

If you clone and run cmake  CMakefileLists.txt && make. The executable (lwm2mserver)is produced.

This runs on Ubuntu Linux but not on ARM/GNU-Linux

Comment: May get more help on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should run `./lwm2server -4` in order to force the use of IPv4. Wakaama defaults to IPv6 in many examples, but if you haven't enabled IPv6 on your Raspberry Pi, then this will cause errors like the one you're mentioning.

Comment: Hi , the latest build contains this option. Earlier the problem was that I was not aware of IPv6 module disabled in my Rpi. I fixed and thanks anyways for your time !